# Canon PIXMA mx439 printer. Won't print the picture included in a Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I am trying to print a lost dog flyer, but the picture in my word document won't print, it just comes out a blur of color. I've tried realigning the cartridges, cleaning the nozzles, re-doing the document. The picture will print directly from the sd card. It shows up fine under print preview. I've done this before without any issues. Help!
I just taped the picture from the sd card over the page where it didn't print and copied it, and that printed ok, so I guessing it's a problem with Word?

Comment: Test does this happen with any other image/documents or just this one?

Comment: Try different ways of putting the picture into Word: use copy/paste,  insert > picture from file, or drag and drop the picture from Explorer. Does any of these methods work?